# how to set the \quad space between the equation and equation number with centered

Tags: spacing

How to set the `\quad` space between the equation and equation number with centered output
i.e equation will be centered the output should be like below

> A + b     (1)
>
> A + b     (2)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is `qud`? Did you try `align`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What you want to achieve is unclear. Please reformulate your question.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - the OP may have meant to write `\quad`. Just a guess.

Comment: I think the OP wants centred equations with equation numbers on the right, albeit not to the far right...

Comment: Does `\[A+b \rlap{\quad(1)}\]` give what you want?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

The usual setting (in \LaTeX\ and generally) is to have the numbers flush to the edge
\begin{align}
    A &+ b \\
    Ax &+ zz
\end{align}

But if you really need this layout you can do the following
(replacing 1em by whatever space you need):

\newcommand\mytag{\hspace*{1em}\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\[
\begin{aligned}
    A &+ b &\mytag\\
    Ax &+ zz &\mytag
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```